# Azure Load Balancer - Remove VM for deployment

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-virtual-machine

We are using a health probe of tcp 443 on our load balancers. Is there a way to remove a vm from the load balancer to deploy to it, or cause the health check to fail while we deploy to the server?

Comment: Do you mean you want to do some change on VM, and don't want traffic  to this VM?

Comment: Yes - that is what I want. I want to remove the vm from the load balancer so that I can deploy code to it without it receiving traffic.

Comment: We can stop application on this VM, also we can remove it from LB backend pools, after configure completed, re-add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood your explanation, you want do some change on your VM, and don't want traffic to this VM.
If I understand it correctly, we can login this VM and **stop** the application which listen on port 443, in this way, the health check will fail.

Also, we can **remove** this VM from Azure load balancer backend pools, after configure it completed, re-add it.

Comment: Ok - thank you. I wasn't sure if there was just a way to programmatically do this like with an f5 - remove it from the pool, but not actually remove it completely. I will give this a shot. Thanks again!

Comment: please test it, Please let me know if you would like further assistance:)

Comment: I'll have to try it in the morning when I'm back at work.

Comment: it almost looks like your kpi is tied to SO rating, is that true? @JasonYe-MSFT

Comment: Sorry - been in meetings all morning. This account is new, so it does not look like I cannot upvote.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm not understanding something here. I log onto the server and stop IIS. Then, when I look at the load balancer, it still shows the server as running. Again - the health probe looks at port 443 using tcp. I guess I can probably remove the server from the load balancer and then re-add it. I guess I was just hoping there was a temporary way to tell the load balancer not to use one server (or more) while we deploy code to it/them. Is removing from the load balancer completely and then re-adding the only way?

Comment: @tony Load balancer show VM is running?  via Azure portal we can't find probe's status, we can enable LB probe status, please follow this link to enable it.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-monitor-log     when you stop your IIS, the port 443 is down, we can use telnet to test this vm with port 443.

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT - sorry, I have been on vacation for a bit. I guess what we are looking for is similar to F5 where you can drain users off a server, not just pull it out. But, it sounds like that is not currently possible. Is that correct?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT - I ended up yanking the server from the lb with powershell, do the deploy, then add it back.  

$azureVM = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $azureResourceGroup -Name $azureMachineName
$nic = (Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $azureResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.VirtualMachine.Id -eq $azureVM.Id})
$nic.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools = $null
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic  

$nic.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools = $loadBalancer.BackendAddressPools
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic